# Trace of the matrix power

Tags: matrices, determinant, exponentiation, trace

Say I have matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix}
a & 0 & -c\\
0 & b & 0\\
-c & 0 & a 
\end{bmatrix}$.

What is matrix trace
tr(A^200)

Thanks much!

Comment: sorry, I had to modify it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may do it by first computing matrix powers and then you may calculate whatever you want. Now question is how to calculate matrix power for a given matrix, say $A$? Your goal here is to develop a useful factorization $A = PDP^{-1}$, when $A$ is $n\times n$ matrix.The matrix $D$ is a diagonal matrix (i.e. entries off the main diagonal are all zeros).
Then $A^k =PD^kP^{-1} $. $D^k$ is trivial to compute. Note that columns of $P$ are n linearly
independent eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: I would like to calculate the trace of the matrix A to to the power k tr(A^k). Thanks much

Comment: By using above mentioned fact it is easy to calculate the matrix power for the large $k$ and then by summing the diagonal elements of $A^k$ you may calculate $trace(A^k)$. If you are not sure I may  give you one simple example.

Comment: ok, thanks :)))

Comment: @ABCD Most welcome :)

Answer (score 11):

For this kind of problems, first you have to get eigenvalues and their corresponding eigenvectors. For this problem,
$$ \lambda_1=b,\lambda_2=a-c,\lambda_3=a+c, v_1=(0,1,0)^T,v_2=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})^T,v_3=(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})^T. $$
Let 
$$ P=(v_1,v_2,v_3)=\left(\begin{matrix}0&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
1&0&0\\
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&0&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{matrix}\right). $$
Then it is easy to check $P^T=P^{-1},P^TAP=\text{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)$. Hence
\begin{eqnarray*}
\text{Tr}(A^{200})&=&\text{Tr}(P^TA^{200}P)\\
&=&\text{Tr}((P^TAP)^{200})\\
&=&\lambda_1^{200}+\lambda_2^{200}+\lambda_3^{200}\\
&=&b^{200}+(a-c)^{200}+(a+c)^{200}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score -6):

You just need to calculate Eigen values bcoz sum of eigen values =$tr(A)$ and if "a" is the eigen value of matrix $A$ then "$a^n$" is the eigen value of $A^n$.
thus,
$$Tr(A^{200})=b^{200}+(a−c)^{200}+(a+c)^{200}$$

Comment: Though you are right, this same answer was given about 3 years back. You have not contributed anything new.

Comment: I disagree. The other answers compute eigenvectors (explicitly, or implicitly in a diagonalization), which is pointless, complicated, and distracts from the main idea that the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues. This should be the accepted answer.